# Code Igniter pagination 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I am having problems with CodeIgniter pagination module.

When I go to click on the links I get a 404 error. As I understand and I may be incorrect, but it would seem that the URI segment which determines the offset is not being read inside the index function of my controller and that code igniter is actually looking for this as a function inside the controller hence throwing the 404 when it cant find it.

I have googled around and checked on the forum to find a solution but have not had any success.  If anyone has any hints or tips that would be great I have included the relevant code from my controller, model and view below.

//Controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = '/yourhistory/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('gallery')->num_rows();  
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 
$data['galleryitems'] = $this->pages_model->get_gallery($config['per_page'], $config['uri_segment']);
$this->load->view('/gallery', $data);
```

//Model

```
function get_gallery($limit, $segment)
 {
  $query = $this->db->get('gallery', $limit, $this->uri->segment($segment));
  if ($query->num_rows > 0)
  {
   foreach($query->result() as $row)
   {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
   return $data;
   }
 }
```

//View

```
 echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its going to fail first off because of your base_url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
```

You need the full path, altho I am just guessing here as you don't provide the URL that is throwing the 404.

Notes on pagination here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I have it working now using base_url().'yourhistory/index/'; obviously pointing to a controller called yourhistory. However this is only temporary as I am using dynamically generated urls which have routes set up to redirect to a controller that loads everything depending on info stored in the db. So yourhistory/index/  won't route to the correct controller as their is no route set up for yourhistory/index/. The only solution I can think of is dynamically generting new routes everytime an item is uploaded. But surely there is abetter way?

Comment: You can set up custom routing within a controller, so only the `yourhistory` part of the url routes to the controller, and the rest is parsed by a [function named `_remap`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)

Answer (score 1):

Your base_url is not correct:

```
//should be something like this
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/controllername/functionname/';
```

See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: Hi this has worked thanks. However all the code in my controller is in the index function like so  base_url().'/yourhistory/index'; Is there a way of removing index?